# Extract a presentation file as PPT on SlideShare app

Tags: applications

I am using [SlideShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.slideshare.mobile) to view presentation. Sometimes I want to transfer the presentation to my PC and view it on projector. However, in the Android app, there is only a save feature to view it offline.

I know I can use its website to download the `.ppt` files, but is there any way to get the `.ppt` from the app?

Comment: Can you find it under data folder of your Internal Storage.?

Comment: @Lucky that assumes the device is rooted. Checking the SD card would be possible without root as well – and is IMHO more likely to be used here, considered that some devices only have low "internal storage".

Comment: @Izzy From the Slideshare faq saving offline slides to external sd card is not allowed even if the phone has external storage and by data folder I meant the `Internal Storage/Android/data/` directory. This is the default directory every app stored the data right? and does this require root to view  the contents of the directory?

Comment: @Lucky ah, misunderstanding. "Internal storage" is `/data/*` – you meant the internal SD card (`/sdcard/Android/data/*`). I've meant both, internal and external SD card. And the part for the *external* SD card seems out of discussion now by your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the presentation saved by this app isn't in `.ppt` format but each slide is sliced into a `.jpg` having a numeric name, and the images are found only under `/data/data/net.slideshare.mobile/files/`

E.g. A presentation with 78 pages was sliced into images with names ranging from `7456179_00.jpg`, `7456179_01.jpg`...`7456179_78.jpg`.

**Note** that all the related presentation images  will be having a numeric string like `7456179` in the beginning of name, which is exactly the `ss_id` defined in the table `slideshows` of database `slideshows` under `/data/data/net.slideshare.mobile/databases/`.

Now, here is the disappointing news because all of the said information probably wouldn't be of any worth to you, since this app has declaration of [`android:allowbackup="false"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806946/4720957) in its `AndroidManifest.xml`. What it means is any non-system/root backup app won't be able to touch this app's data, including `ADB` and **Helium** which I deliberately try despite clear evidence of failure. It seems that there isn't much of a choice left to backup the presentation (or what has become of it).

**What's next?** There is one thing that I can think of. If your device is not rooted and you're or can make yourself aware of extracting backup made by your device's Recovery, then go ahead and take backup from it since Recovery doesn't care or even know those "disallow backup declarations", and it should take backup of your app too, among other things.

#### For root users

You now know what to do:

- You can copy-paste images from  `/data/data/net.slideshare.mobile/files/` into your SD card and then into PC, or may be do `adb pull`,
- You can also find out easily which `ss_id` belongs to which presentation using an SQL query or an app like [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor),
- You can take backup by [Titanium Backup](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb), export it, and extract it to see the files,
- and any possible way you can think of. :)

Answer (score 0):

1)Open slideshare.net on ur browser in your phone.
2)Then,from the dropdown menu in your browser,select the option "request desktop site".
3)The download option on the slideshare page will be available now.

Note:- These restrictions have been implemented only on mobile users in order to boost the slideshare app.

WELCOME;)

Comment: OP already knew about that: "*When I use its website then i can download the .ppt files.*"